# How to Limit Total Publishable Posts?

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

Thanks for your attention.

I would like to limit the number of posts possible at any given time on one of my blogs in WordPress Multisite.  Conceptually I'd just like to get an idea of how this is done, what the proper hook would be, and maybe some idea of how to approach limiting.  Don't need you to write code necessarily, just trying to understand.  Thanks a lot!

PS: Should only apply to Posts, and not any other custom content types.

Comment: You may want to check this plugin out, and see how they're doing it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/

Comment: Are you trying to limit how many can be viewed on the front-end?

Comment: No, I'm trying to limit total publishable posts.